# How to solve: `network` field in `brownie-config.yaml` has been deprecated. now handled via `brownie networks` in the CLI"

Tags: python, brownie

Been following a blockchain brownie tutorial and currently have network specific custom fields setup in `brownie-config.yaml` as such

```
network:
  development:
    verify: False
  ganache-local:
    verify: False
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    verify: True
```

I get the following warning

```
DeprecationWarning: The `network` field in `brownie-config.yaml` has been deprecated. Network settings are now handled via `brownie networks` in the CLI. Remove `network` from E:\Code\Solidity\demos\brownie_fund_me\brownie-config to silence this warning.
```

I have looked at the docs but I am unsure how to use the cli to add fields to my existing network `Ethereum > ganache-local`

I have tried: `brownie networks modify  ganache-local verify=False` but this does not work `"ValueError: Unknown field(s): verify"`

Answer (score 0):

it's `networks` not `network`

the correct structure is

```
networks:
  development:
    verify: False
  ganache-local:
    verify: False
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    verify: True
```

notice the **s** in **networks** now